# Hiding Sencha Touch carousel bullets

Tags: sencha-touch

I am going to use Sencha Touch 2 carousel in a mobile view but I need to hide the navigation bullets at the bottom of it. Is there a config for this (I looked through the api but couldn't find one), or should I use CSS to hide them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, only put into `config: {}` block of `Ext.Carousel` element, something like this

```
        indicator: false
```

and have fun! hidden. I hope this helps. :)